# remainder term error in maclaurin polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider function f(x)=$\frac{1}{1-x}$, find the remainder term Rn(Z) of a function of x and n.

I now know that $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}} $ and that $Rn(z)=\frac{f^{n+1}(z)}{(n+1)!}(x)^{n+1}$ but im not sure how to find the answer without using Z.

Cheers for any help

Comment: There should be $-1^n$ somewhere in the $f^n(x)$.

Comment: Note that you want $\frac{1}{1-x}-(1+x+\cdots+x^n)$. Do you know a formula for $1+x+\cdots+x^n$ ?

Comment: Your expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$ was correct without $(-1)^{n+1}$. Compute the case $n=2$ to see it.

Comment: ok thankyou @Kelenner, im just having trouble seeing the answer, i think $1+x+...+x^n $ is equal to $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ however when i put it in the answer says its wrong, im not sure what bit im not understanding correctly

Comment: Yes, your computation seems good, what answer it is given to you ?

Comment: I'm assuming Rn(z)=$\frac{1}{1-x}$-$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ but the program is saying answer is wrong

Comment: Perhaps you have to simplify: $R_n=\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. Or you are asked $1/(1-x)-(1+x+\cdot+x^{n-1})$.

Comment: I've tried both but neither work, thanks anyway for your help